# 'hasOwnProperty' in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use `obj.hasOwnProperty` to judge whether this object has this property, but when I replaced `obj[prop] !== undefined`, but not normal implementation, I would like to ask, why behind this method can not use it?

```
object.hasOwnProperty(prop);
object[prop] !== undefined;
```

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand… what exact problem are you experiencing? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: An object can have a property that has the value `undefined`. This is not the same thing as the property not existing. So `object[prop] !== undefined` does not test whether the property exists.

Comment: Can you re add the question? can't understand what you are trying to do and trying to ask.

Comment: `object[prop]` will return a property that's inherited from the prototype. `hasOwnProperty` doesn't follow the prototype chain.

Answer (score 3):

`obj[prop] !== undefined` is wrong for two reasons:

1. You can explicitly set a property to `undefined`, with `obj[prop] = undefined;`. `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` will return `true` in this case.
2. `obj[prop]` will follow the prototype chain, so it will return a property that's inherited. `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` only returns `true` if the property exists directly in the object, it returns `false` for inherited properties.